# sed: inserting text before end of <HEAD> section

Tags: text-processing, sed, osx

I need to insert some text into an HTML file before the end of the `HEAD` section.

I'm trying:

```
sed -i "s#</head>#<style> @page { prince-shrink-to-fit: auto }
.repository-with-sidebar.with-full-navigation .repository-content 
{width: 950px ! important;} </style>\n</head>#" ${1}"/"${2}"/"${i}.html
```

I'm getting an error:

```
sed: 1: command a expects \ followed by text
```

I just don't see my error. I even tried using single quotes around the style.

The exact text I want to insert before the end of the `HEAD` section is:

```
<style>
@page { prince-shrink-to-fit: auto }
.repository-with-sidebar.with-full-navigation .repository-content 
{width: 950px ! important;}
</style>
```

Edit: Here is the exact command:

```
sed -i "s#</head>#<style> @page { prince-shrink-to-fit: auto } .repository-with-sidebar.with-full-navigation .repository-content {width: 950px ! important;} </style>\n</head>#" ${1}"/"${2}"/"${i}.html
```

Edit 2: In an effort to try and make sure I was formatting the command correctly I am trying this too:

```
strToInsert='<style> @page { prince-shrink-to-fit: auto } .repository-with-sidebar.with-full-navigation .repository-content {width: 950px ! important;} </style>'

sed -i "s#</head>#$strToInsert\n</head>#" ${1}"/"${2}"/"${i}.html
```

This makes me realize it might be a problem with the text I am inserting.

Comment: 1) Are those newlines literally inside the quotes? 2) Are you on BSD or OSX?

Comment: @MichaelHomer no, sorry I just did that for easy SO formatting. I am on OS X technically

Comment: Please provide the command exactly as you're using it. I've just written an answer (and now abandoned it) about your multiline `sed`.

Comment: (1) Why does the "exact text" not include `</head>`?  (2) Your command, with extraneous newlines removed, works fine for me (GNU sed).  As roaima asks, please show __exactly__ what command you are running.

Comment: If you are on OS X, why on earth have you tagged it "linux"?

Comment: I'm trying on both OS X and Ubuntu.

Comment: That is specifically the error message from OS X `sed`, and it does not occur at all on Ubuntu's default `sed`. You will get better answers to your questions if you provide accurate information.

Answer (score 4):

In-place `sed` requires making a backup file during the process. The [`-i` option on Apple's `sed` requires an extension argument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) (for the backup file it creates) and consumes the next argument. That means you're telling it you want it to make a backup file with the extension "`#s</head>#...`".

The error means it thinks you're referring to the [`a`ppend command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Appending-text-after-a-line-128). I'm going to guess that the value of `$1` starts with an `a`. Because `-i` ate the preceding argument `sed` thinks that this is the script to run, rather than the path to the file to change, and you get errors accordingly. This is exactly the error you would get with Apple `sed` and an invalid `a` command:

> ```
> $ sed a
> sed: 1: "a": command a expects \ followed by text
> ```

Provide an extension argument to `-i` in your `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bak "s#</head>#<style> @page { prince-shrink-to-fit: auto } .repository-with-sidebar.with-full-navigation .repository-content {width: 50px ! important;} </style>\n</head>#" "${1}/${2}/${i}.html"
```

and things will work (although note that `\n` is not a newline escape). If you use single quotes you can even take the space out of "`!important`".

The above will work on GNU `sed` as well, but note that [`-i` is not a POSIX option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and is not generally portable.

It is often recommended not to use in-place modification anyway, and to handle working with a copy of the file explicitly yourself. That is up to you, though.

---

You should quote the variable expansions `${1}`, etc. Quoting only the slashes is pointless, because those are always literal.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I understand. I should have looked at the man page better. I totally missed this.

Comment: @GameDeveloper If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

My apologies, but reading your statement *The exact text I want to insert after end of the HEAD section is...* led me initially to believe we were talking about appending text to file section rather than inserting before - so I wrote that answer first. After rereading the question, and more closely studying your example `sed` command - I think I understand this really is about inserting text before a match. So that answer is now here as well - you'll find instructions below for doing either thing.

To safely `i`nsert or `a`ppend an arbitrary string to the head/tail of a line w/ `sed` you have a few options, each more complex than the last.

The first - and the most simple of all - is the `r`ead command. It requires zero escaping. For example, if the string you wanted to append was located in the file `./append` you could just do:

```sh
sed '\|</head>|r ./append' <infile >outfile
```

Or to insert it *ahead* of the match you can match it one cycle before it is printed with a little lookahead like:

```sh
sed -e '$!N;\|\n</head>|r ./insert' -e 'P;D' <infile >outfile
```

But `r`ead is spec'd to write to stdout - and I'm not sure how that would work w/ the `-i`nplace option *(which is mostly just an ugly hack in my opinion, anyway)*. I *assume* that `sed` should do the same thing it does w/ `p`rint and redirect stdout to its named `-i`nplace edit file.

Another option is to use the `a`ppend command - for *appending* that is. To do this safely you need only escape `\n`ewlines and backslashes. You might do this like:

```sh
printf %s\\n "$str_to_append" |
sed 's|\\|&&|g;$!s|$|\\|;1i\
    \\|</head>|a\\' |
sed -f - infile >outfile
```

`a`ppend is spec'd to behave as `r`ead does, though, and so I am again unsure how it might behave in an `-i`n-place hack.

If you replace `a\\` above w/ `i\\` it will `i`nsert the text to stdout *(or named `-i`nplace edit-file - if that works for your implementation)* *before* the pattern space is written out.

If you like extra work, *(or, in the only practical use I can think of, you're scheduling multiple `r`eads/`a`ppends per line in a certain order)* it can be used for inserts as well in the same way I did with `r`ead before:

```sh
printf %s\\n "$str_to_append" |
sed 's|\\|&&|g;$!s|$|\\|;1i\
    \\|\\n</head>|a\\' |
sed -e '$!N' -f - -e 'P;D' infile >outfile
```

The last I'll offer is nearly identical except that you must also escape `&` and *delimiter* *(which is typically `/`)*. It could work like this:

```sh
printf %s\\n "$str_to_append" |
sed 's|[\/&]|\\&|g
   $!s|$|\\|;$s|$|/|
     1i\
     /<\\/head>/s/^/\\' |
sed -f - infile >outfile
```

That will effect an insertion - you would just swap the `^` with a `$` if you wished to append the string that way.

I'm fairly confident that will work whether you add the `-i` option or not.

One last note, though - rather than using `-i`, you might also do:

```sh
sed '$d;\|</head>|r ./append' <<IN >infile
$(   cat <infile; echo .)
IN
```

...or, for an insert:

```sh
sed -e '$d;N;\|\n</head>|r ./insert' -e 'P;D' <<IN >infile
$(   cat <infile; echo .)
IN
```

...which will get your *infile* edited in-place without any unintended permissions hiccups as `-i` might effect.

Comment: That last is a really cute trick.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - I just realized this was about inserting text *before* the line in question.

Comment: @don_crissti - you're gettting *really* good w/ `sed`. Thanks for showing others how, too. You might like [this](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) - I found it rather self-affirming anyway. A new thing I noticed about `sed` the other day: compare `echo now | cat - /dev/tty | sed -n w\ /dev/fd/1 | cat - /dev/tty` to `echo when\? | cat - /dev/tty | sed -n p | cat - /dev/tty`. Remember that GNU `cat` never buffers, and I only stuck them in there to demo `sed`'s behavior in the middle of a pipeline with an unending stream.

Comment: @don_crissti  - right - `w`rite has to take effect immediately because `r`ead [takes effect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) at *the time the output is written, not the time the `r` command is applied* - which could enable a particularly masochistic `sed`er to recursively edit one or more files. Anyway, the input is always line-buffered *(without `-u` or `-z`)*, and so you can always also line-buffer output by getting specific about the `w`rite files. I've been working on-and-off on a simple, shell-agnostic readline replacement for a long time and that helps.